# pulse audio defaults soundcard speakers as headphones

Tags: linux, debian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Pulseaudio is defaulting my default output device as headphones from my desktop soundcard.  Previously I could select headphones or speakers, but now it only says headphones.  This is a problem because now the pulse mixer tells alsa to adjust the headphone volume instead of the speakers.  Alsa dutifully does this, which means my computer speaker volume does not change, only the (not plugged in) headphones.  Its kind of an annoyance because I can't use my multimedia keys that are mapped to pulseaudio.  Any suggestions?  I tried mapping them directly to the soundcard, but again they only change the headphone only volume.

Annoying indeed.  Any help would be appreciated.